# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User' when trying to run the SQL in Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I'm trying to populate Excel with the data from SQL Server, however when I go to Microsoft query and after I select what I wish to see it returns back with an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'

I have tried to add [] or "" and nothing works.

```
SELECT User.id, User.company
FROM MyDB.dbo.User User
```

I have replaced `User` with `[User]` or `"User"` but that doesn't work. If you have any idea how I can get the data from the database, please let me know.

I cannot rename the database as the software will not going to work anymore.

Comment: Did you enclose all of the occurrences of the `User` keyword in your query in square brackets? If so, and it doesn't work, add the query you tried to your question.

Answer (score 2):

`USER` is a [Reserved Keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in SQL Server. Don't use them for object names; if you have I recommend changing the name.

If you do *have* to refer to an object which uses a Reserved Keyword, you have to quote it. I.e. `[User]`.

For your query, that would be:

```
SELECT U.id,
       U.company
FROM MyDB.dbo.[User] U; --Changed Alias because alasing an object to its own name
                        --And a reserved keyword is not a good idea.
```

Comment: Glad it works @Svan. Please do mark the answer as the solution if so, so that future users know that the answer helped. Thanks.